# Is there a term for the opposite of an interpolation?

Tags: functions, terminology

The question is specifically about [linear Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), which is usually defined to be a function
$$
f : V \times V \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow V \\
f(v_0,v_1,\alpha) = v_0 + (v_1-v_0) \cdot \alpha
$$
So it takes the arguments $v_0$ and $v_1$ and a real value $\alpha$ (often, but not necessarily, in $[0,1]$), and computes the linearly interpolated value.

Conversely, there may be a function like this:
$$
g : V \times V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
g(v_0,v,v_1) = (v - v_0) / (v_1 - v_0)
$$
For the given arguments, it computes the "relative position" of one element between the others - namely, the value that could be used as the $\alpha$ value in the interpolation function, so that $f(v_0, v_1, g(v_0, v, v_1)) = v$.

It's not an "inverse", and the term "opposite" in the title was just for lack of a better term. Right now, I'm calling it ~"interpolation parameter function", but I wonder whether there is a commonly used term for that.

Comment: I don't feel confident that this is the best description, and it probably couldn't be used without explanation, but I might describe that as [a barycentric coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system). Edit: wait, I assumed $v$ had to be on the line containing the other two (the affine span of them).

Comment: It is in fact an inverse after you "curry" your functions in the right way. Namely $g(v_0,\cdot,v_1)$ is an inverse of $f(v_0,v_1,\cdot)$.

Comment: @MarkS. That's indeed pretty close already (and I wonder why I didn't think of this yet). The fact that barycentric coordinates are mainly interpreted *geometrically* means that it does not fit perfectly in the most generic sense, but if nobody posts a better answer in the next days, I'd probably ping you to turn the comment into an answer and accept it as being "as close as it gets".

Comment: @Ian Yes, it can be boiled down to an inverse, but would require an additional description then - basically, some "verbal un-currying". Just calling it the "inverse of the interpolation" would not be sufficient, I guess...

Comment: @MarkS. Regarding the edit: I don't think that being contained in the simplex is a *necessary* condition for computing the barycentric coordinates, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: @Marco13 I agree; it doesn't have to be in the simplex (the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)), but it has to be in the line (the [affine hull/span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull)). Since your domain of $g$ was written as $V\times V\times V$, I wasn't certain if you intended for $v$ to lie on the line containing $v_0$ and $v_1$.

Comment: @MarkS. If I understood correctly, then this would just be the the difference of $\alpha$ either being in $[0,1]$ (convex hull) or in $\mathbb{R}$ (affine space). If so, maybe I should have omitted the "$[0,1]$" part in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being clear because I wanted avoid assumptions. I think we both agree on what you want $g$ to do and how the phrase "barycentric coordinates" is often used. But you have a typo in the question since if $V$ is more than one dimensional, then either $g$ is a partial function, or you don't actually want the middle component of the domain "$V\times V\times V$" to be all of $V$.

Comment: @MarkS. Ok, although I usually *try* to be precise, I might not have been precise enough here. I think that you (*roughly*) referred to the point that $v$ must be an affine combination of $v_0$ and $v_1$ in the first place. E.g. if $V = \mathbb{R}^3$, and $v_0 = (0,0,1)$, $v_1 = (0,1,0)$ then there would be no solution for $v = (1,0,0)$. (I'll think about how to describe it more clearly, although this might be a case where attempting to be more (formally) precise might distract from the point of the question...)

Comment: @MarkS. As mentioned above: Barycentric coordinates seems to be as close as it gets to a sensible word for this. If you wrote an answer (probably mentioning the constraint that $v$ must be an affine combination of $v_0$ and $v_1$ etc), I'd accept it, otherwise, I'd self-answer it, referring to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the question, given a real vector space $V$, we can define a function for parametrizing lines between vectors by $$
f : V \times V \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow V \\
f(\mathbf v_0,\mathbf v_1,\alpha) = \mathbf v_0 + (\mathbf v_1-\mathbf v_0) \cdot \alpha\text{.}
$$

If $\mathbf v_0\ne\mathbf v_1$, then $\alpha\mapsto f(\mathbf v_0,\mathbf v_1,\alpha)$ certainly defines an injective function $\mathbb R\to V$, with image line $\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf v_0\mathbf v_1}$. Thus, we can define a bijective function $F_{\mathbf v_0,\mathbf v_1}:\mathbb R\to \overleftrightarrow{\mathbf v_0\mathbf v_1}$.

The inverse is given by $F_{\mathbf v_0,\mathbf v_1}^{-1}:\mathbf v\mapsto\dfrac{\mathbf v-\mathbf v_0}{\mathbf v_1-\mathbf v_0}$, where the division is to be interpreted as yielding the relevant scalar multiple, as mentioned in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/246622/26369). This inverse could be described as providing the [**barycentric coordinate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Barycentric_coordinates) for the input point on the line $\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf v_0\mathbf v_1}$ with respect to the [affine basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Affine_span_and_bases) $(\mathbf v_0,\mathbf v_1)$.

---

As alluded to in the original post, we could combine these inverses together as a single function, though writing the domain properly is a bit cumbersome. We could define $$g:\left\{(\mathbf v_0,\mathbf v,\mathbf v_1)\left|\mathbf v_0\ne\mathbf v_1\text{ and } \mathbf v\in\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf v_0\mathbf v_1}\right.\right\}\to \mathbb R$$ $$g(\mathbf v_0,\mathbf v,\mathbf v_1)= F_{\mathbf v_0,\mathbf v_1}^{-1}(\mathbf v)\text{.}$$